# Showing Trigger DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, dbms-output

I have a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Med_Allergy_Warning BEFORE INSERT ON Prescription FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (Find_ADR(:NEW.Visit_ID, :NEW.Medication_ID) != 'GOOOO') THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Medication ('||:NEW.Medication_ID||') May cause an allergic reaction… You are warned!');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Medication ('||:NEW.Medication_ID||') was prescribed successfully!');
END IF;
END;/
```

That outputs a DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE whenever a user enters a prescription that may cause allergic reactions. However, the user creates the entry in APEX - is there anyway to create a region to show this DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE message on the same page?

Comment: Please, tell me this code won't get into any real medical application !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, you should be able to call `DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE` to get the data in your APEX code and display that.  However, building application functionality that depends on writing to `DBMS_OUTPUT` is a terrible approach.  If you want to log information about potential allergic reactions, you really, really ought to log that to a table that your APEX application can then report on.  Hoping that whatever application issues the `INSERT` has enabled `DBMS_OUTPUT` let alone allocated a large enough buffer for the output let alone happened to remember to read from the buffer and display that to a human is a really bad idea.